# JSON Serialization error with simplejson

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have the following code:

```
data = {'services': [u'iTunes'], 
        'orders': [u'TestOrder', u'Test_April_Titles_iTunes'],
        'providers': ''}

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in default
  178.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /reports/change_dropdown/
Exception Value: [u'iTunes'] is not JSON serializable
```

What do I need to do to serialize this dictionary with a list inside it?

Comment: What version of `simplejson` are you using? I'm pretty sure this Unicode support was added a long time ago. More importantly, why are you using `simplejson` instead of the version built in to the stdlib, `json`, in 2.7?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `itunes` is a non-JSON compatible type.

To solve provide default type to convert non-JSON compatible types when serializing:

```
simplejson.dumps(data, default=str))
```

or even:

```
def handler(val):
    if isinstance(val, unicode)
        return str(val)
    else:
        return val

simplejson.dumps(data, default=handler))
```

The advantage of the second option is you can handle sets (e.g., convert to list), dates (e.g., convert to int timetstamp), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from `unicode` to `str` worked here:

```
data['services'] = [str(item) for item in data['services']]
data['orders'] = [str(item) for item in data['orders']]
data['providers'] = [str(item) for item in data['providers']]
```

Comment: JSON handles unicode just fine. I think your types are not unicode; perhaps they are BeautifulSoup NavigableText instances instead? Try converting them to *`unicode()`* instead.. You most definitely want to check their `type()` next time.

Comment: Even if you're using a format (or library) that doesn't handle Unicode, if you have any non-ASCII strings, you never want to just convert `unicode` to `str`. If you know what the charset is, use `item.encode('UTF-8')` (or whatever). If you _don't_ know what the charset is… you probably want to use `'unicodeescape'`, so you can funnel it through an 8-bit pipe and recover it on the other end.